# The paradox of majority power vs. contracts

Tags: democracy, political-theory, reference-request

For this question, let us assume that the only principle we care about in public decision making is majority power: the majority of citizens should be able to do whatever they want. There seems to be an inherent paradox in this principle. For example, suppose that in 2022, the majority of citizens in some country decides to sign a contract with some external entity. In 2023, when it's time to pay, the majority decides to break the contract and not pay. If the contract cannot be enforced, this means that no-one has an incentive to sign contracts with this country. So, the effective power of the majority is greatly reduced - they cannot commit, so no-one will want to sign contracts with them.

The paradox here is that, giving the majority absolute power (including the power to break contracts) greatly reduces the power of majority (the power to have contracts).

A common solution in democratic countries is to give courts the power to enforce contracts, even against the will of the majority. However, this power limits the power of the majority and may be abused to give excessive power to the judges (for example, the judges might interpret the contract in a way that favors themselves or the values they believe in, which might contradict the views of majority).

My question: are there any studies in political theory (or elsewhere) regarding this paradox, and its possible solutions?

Comment: I don't think this is just limited to popular majorities. _Any_ government can have this problem. That said, I'm not sure what the paradox is here.  The majority can't literally do "whatever they want" - they can't vote to give everyone the power to fly by flapping their arms, for example. Since they're constrained by real world limitations, that includes not having any authority over external entities, so being unable to sign a contract with such an external entity (after violating earlier ones) is no more or less a limitation on them than the laws of physics are.

Comment: Depending exactly what one means by contract, a typical arrangement is for it to have some arbitration provision to be carried out by a court *outside* the country in question. Of course, by Westphalian sovereignty any country (regardless of gov't type) can reject an external court like that, but there could be consequences, ranging from "fool me twice" to sanctions, and in older times, "gunboat diplomacy" etc. I, like @Bobson find the focus on majority rule totally irrelevant here.

Comment: Example of olde https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venezuelan_crisis_of_1902%E2%80%931903

Answer (score 1):

You should consider two different questions here:

- **Contracts with outside entities.**
  States *are* sovereign, and a state defaulting on a debt or contract is a normal business risk in international commerce and investment. Investors and merchants cover it by looking at the reputation of the state, and possibly by "buying insurance." (Insurance against credit non-payments are called [credit default swaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_default_swap). There are also [bilateral investment treaties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Investor-state_dispute_settlement), but those will fail if a state "burns all bridges" with international commerce. A worse risk causes a [credit spread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yield_spread).)
- **Contracts with internal entities.**
  A sovereign state has the right to interfere with normal business activity if that is deemed necessary. Consider the [Defense Production Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_Production_Act_of_1950) in the United States. It is up to each state to *define*, perhaps in their constitution, just how far they allow their parliaments to go. But a state which accepts the absolute right of a majority to make decisions cannot have a constitution, right?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem. On one hand "pacta sunt servanda" is a long-standing pillar of law systems, on the other hand contracts get violated all the time without people loosing trust in each other completely.

Maybe you really want to know how long decisions by ancestors in the past should be binding for successors in the future? Or under which circumstances a bad contract should reasonably be cancelable? Or maybe in general the relation of the law system to democracy? Or democracies and international contracts?

In any case one potential example about this not being a big problem:

UK is a democracy based on majority voting (in each voting district, in Parliament) and they negotiated Brexit but may soon invoke Article 16 to be able to get around some provisions in that treaty that the UK doesn't particularly likes. That could be seen as breaching a contract and maybe it even is but also doesn't mean that nobody makes business with the UK anymore. A possible retaliation if any occurs would probably also be strictly limited to the EU-UK economic relations. Something like tit for tat.

In the end the thing is that contracts are only paper or promises and promises can be broken. It all depends on how much trust you put in them. There is not much direct connection to democracy there.